# How can Postfix smtp server scan or calculate the md5sum of an attachment while it enters to my server?

Tags: shell-script, files, email, postfix, filter

How can a Postfix SMTP server scan or calculate the md5sum of an attachment which arrived to my server?

The issue comes from a recurring attachment that is sent with different body and different email addresses. and the file attached in a different name every time. therefore, the attachment header lines in the email file (.eml) does not help at all. That's why I want to extract the attachment somewhere aside, maybe, for example in /tmp, in a filter script and calculate the md5sum of the file in order to reject this email.

update: from calculating the MD5SUM I can know that this is the file I am looking for even if its name is changed.

In case they would help, I have clamav installed, and I have spamassin installed too.

Comment: What purpose would that checksum serve afterwards?

Comment: simply, I can know that this is the file I am looking for no matter how they change its name.